# Webdriver findElement fails on 32bit IE browsers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using the latest Selenium code, 2.25 IEDriver 2.25.2 32 bit, IE 8 32 bit on Windows XP. Using the simple code listing below, I never get to the "Found element!!" line if I use InternetExplorerDriver. It opens the page, reads the page title but fails on the findElement call. If I swap to FirefoxDriver it works. I have been able to get IE 9 64 bit to work on a remote PC through the hub (uncomment first two lines and comment out the two WebDriver lines).

Don't understand why this fails for IE 32 bit.

===========================================

```
package com.company.test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException
    {
        // Grid driver
//        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
//        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        // Local driver
//        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        try {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/");
            String pageTitle = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println("pageTitle=" + pageTitle);
            driver.findElement(By.id("q")).clear();
            System.out.println("Found element!!");
            driver.findElement(By.id("q")).sendKeys("test");
            driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

============================================================

I was able to get the IEDriver to generate TRACE logs Here is the snippet of interest:

```
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 IECommandExecutor.cpp(604) Entering IECommandExecutor::LocateElement
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 IECommandExecutor.cpp(587) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetElementFindMethod
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 ElementFinder.cpp(33) Entering ElmentFinder::FindElement
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 IECommandExecutor.cpp(439) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetCurrentBrowser
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 IECommandExecutor.cpp(445) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetManagedBrowser
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 ElementFinder.cpp(468) Entering ElementFinder::SanitizeCriteria
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 ElementFinder.cpp(479) Entering ElementFinder::ReplaceAllSubstrings
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 ElementFinder.cpp(479) Entering ElementFinder::ReplaceAllSubstrings
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 Browser.cpp(91) Entering Browser::GetDocument
I 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 Browser.cpp(95) No child frame focus. Focus is on top-level frame
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:516 IECommandExecutor.cpp(187) Entering IECommandExecutor::OnGetResponseLength
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:532 IECommandExecutor.cpp(187) Entering IECommandExecutor::OnGetResponseLength
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:532 Browser.cpp(451) Entering Browser::GetDocumentFromWindow
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:532 Script.cpp(40) Entering Script::Initialize
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:532 Script.cpp(210) Entering Script::Execute
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:532 Script.cpp(577) Entering Script::CreateAnonymousFunction
T 2012-08-09 16:04:09:547 IECommandExecutor.cpp(187) Entering IECommandExecutor::OnGetResponseLength
W 2012-08-09 16:04:09:547 Script.cpp(594) -2147024891 [Access is denied.]: Unable to execute code, call to IHTMLWindow2::execScript failed
W 2012-08-09 16:04:09:547 Script.cpp(221) Cannot create anonymous function
W 2012-08-09 16:04:09:547 ElementFinder.cpp(86) Unable to create criteria object for mechanism 00FBA030 and criteria00FB9FB0
```

I believe the issue is with the highlighted sections in red above, but I don't know how to fix the issue. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: (1) There is no red highlighting in the text you posted (I don't think that's possible in SO). Can you tell us what section you're referring to? (2) You said your test "fails on the findElement call". Does it throw an exception? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Check your browser security settings to ensure that Active Scripting is enabled.  To enable in IE9 do the following: 
1. Click on the "Tools" icon. (Tools icon is on the top right-hand corner of IE9, or Tools can also be found on the Menu bar as "Tools"). 
2. Then click -> Internet Options" -> Security tab -> Custom Level button -> Scroll to the "Scripting" section near the bottom, and under "Active scripting" select Enable. 
3. Click OK.

Comment: I have the same message as the OP, and this didn't help.